# XOR gate from resistors

Tags: resistors

What I want to achieve is a simple circuit that pretty much implements an XOR gate using resistors (not transistors). Is it possible?

Edit per request:
I am studying possible ways to implement an XOR gate using resistors to implement as a computation in memory. This is an emerging technology where data is processed while it is being stored in memory. I am implementing some encryption and using XOR logic to encrypt my data. The type of memory I am using is resistive memory (also emerging technology that uses resistors to store data).

I am planning to implement an online (or in real-time) encryption process using XOR gates. If I am able to implement XOR gates using resistors, I will have a memory that acts as a memory and an encryption box.

Comment: I'm almost 100% certain this is not possible.

Comment: You might want to start with an inverter. Is that possible?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany how you suggest that?

Comment: It’s not possible, well unless you cheat in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

An XOR gate is a logic device and is tricky enough to make with transistors.

You could make an XOR gate with a pair of switches or relays.

[image: schematic]
*An XOR constructed of switches or relays.*

Comment: Mhhm, I think this is one solution I can consider. Thank you!

Comment: It would be a big help if you edited your question to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added explanation of what I want to do

Comment: Resistive memory is, as the name suggests, a memory device, not a logic device.

Comment: Yes, but the cells can behave as a resistor (thus my question if you can make a logic gate from resistors). I already have read a few papers that achieved a level of computation in memory using simple combinations of resistive memory (mostly AND and OR gates).

Comment: @Transistor OP is talking about memristors which behaves somewhat like diodes in DC. And with a diode you can easily create an OR gate or an AND gate. It's very fascinating to me that OP chose to not mention any paper or the word memristor.

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, the output voltage of any circuit built with resistors alone can only increase as the input voltages increase.  Since 0 xor 1 = 1 and 1 xor 1 = 0, the XOR gate has an output that can decrease as one of its inputs increases.  Therefore it cannot be built from resistors.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the explanation. I believe I got a bit carried away with a project I am working on.